# Vim substitute with shell command output to which regex group is passed as parameter

Tags: vim, substitution

I am aware of special \= sequence that allows substitution to be interpreted as an expression - I am curious if its possible to pass matched group to the expression somehow.

For example, this worked perfectly (replace '50' with random shuffle in range between -7 and 7):

```
%s/50/\=substitute(system('echo $(shuf -i 1-14 -n1) - 7 | bc'), '\n', '', 'g')/gc
```

What I'd love, is the ability to capture '50' in the group and pass it to the command.

From what I found in help, it says:

> "The special meaning for characters as mentioned at |sub-replace-special|
>   does
>   not apply except for < CR >."

which, from what I understood, means that special sequences such as group backreferences won't be interpreted and supplied to the expression accordingly.

If I'm wrong, or I'm right but there's a workaround - sharing your trick would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I only spent few more minutes looking, I'd found the answer myself.
Anyway - the answer lies in 'submatch()' function which does exactly what i need.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution using 'submatch() function' please?

Comment: Given that I had this problem in 2016, and we're 2023 now - unfortunately I can't recall at all.